# Comprobar si existe un xpath determinado en la web o no

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, selenium

Estoy extrayendo datos de una web a través de xpath con selenium, la cuestión es que ese xpath no siempre esta disponible en la web ya que la web varia, y cuando no esta disponible pues da error el while, como podría comprobar que hay algo dentro del xpath o bien si existe.

```
usuarios=[]

def inicio():

    h1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="main"]/header/div[2]/div[2]/span')

    usuarios.append(h1.text)

    print (usuarios)

    time.sleep(5)

while True:
    inicio()
```

así funciona bien y se van introduciendo en la lista, pero cuando el xpath desaparece da error y se para todo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes simplemente usar un **try** y **except** para que en caso de no encontrar el elemento, ignore el problema y siga intentando luego:

```
usuarios=[]

def inicio():
    
    try: # Intenta identificar el elemento, si lo hace, el resto de instrucciones dentro del 'try' se ejecutan

        h1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="main"]/header/div[2]/div[2]/span')

        usuarios.append(h1.text)

        print (usuarios)

    except: # Sino, ejecuta lo que se encuentre en el 'except'

        pass # En este caso, solo lo ignora sin hacer nada

    time.sleep(5)

while True:
    inicio()
```